# I need a driver for my Cardbus USB 2.0 card

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, pcmcia

The picture and details of the card are here: http://www.ht-link.com/en/ProductView.asp?ID=106  The Windows drivers for this don't work right. I tried them on my previous laptop, and then installed the ones off their included CD.  (Note that the systems requirements includes a CD-ROM drive...) I have a new laptop, and lost the CD. The website that lists the drivers is broken - the download links don't work.  It is here: http://www.ht-link.com/en/DownView.asp?ID=10  I need the very first link - The Win XP drivers for the HT-112NEC.  The company does not reply to my e-mails. I've tried searching Google for other sources for the driver (I didn't bother with those sites that want me to install driver detection software or create a log-in for their site).

[Here's the problem I am getting using the drivers Windows XP SP3 installs:  When I plug in my USB 2.0 hard-disk adapter, a USB Mass Storage Device entry is added in the Device Manager, but there is no entry under Disk Drives, and a drive letter is not assigned, so I can't access the driver.  Like I said, this card didn't work without their special drivers on my other laptop, either.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer has now sent me the driver.